# Contour integration help: $\int_{\gamma}e^zdz$ with $\gamma(\theta)$=$e^{i\theta}$

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

I am stuck integrating $$\int_{\gamma}e^zdz$$
with $\gamma(\theta)$=$e^{i\theta}$ and $0\le\theta\le2\pi$.
I got up to $$\int_{\gamma}e^zdz = \int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{e^{i\theta}}\cdot ie^{i\theta}d\theta = \int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos\theta+i\sin\theta}\cdot i(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)d\theta.$$

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen the Cauchy Integral Theorem??

Comment: Ray: could you explain the meaning of your Edit and why @Sasha's post does not answer your needs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The integrand $\mathrm{e}^z$ is holomorphic for $\vert z \vert \le 1$ (check that), therefore the integral vanishes by the Cauchy integral theorem ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_analysis#Major_results)).

Now let's look at it like you do:
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
  \int_0^{2 \pi} \mathrm{e}^{\cos(\theta)} \cos(\theta + \sin(\theta)) \mathrm{d} \theta &=&
   \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} \theta} \left( \mathrm{e}^{\cos(\theta)} \sin(\sin(\theta))  \right) \mathrm{d} \theta = \left. \mathrm{e}^{\cos(\theta)} \sin(\sin(\theta)) \right|_0^{2\pi} = 0
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Indeed:
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
  \mathrm{e}^{\cos(\theta)} \cos(\theta + \sin(\theta)) &=&  \mathrm{e}^{\cos(\theta)} \cos(\theta) \cos(\sin(\theta)) -  \mathrm{e}^{\cos(\theta)}  \sin(\theta) \sin(\sin(\theta) \\ 
   &=& \mathrm{e}^{\cos(\theta)} \cdot  \frac{\mathrm{d} \sin(\sin(\theta))}{\mathrm{d} \theta} + 
      \frac{\mathrm{d} \mathrm{e}^{\cos(\theta)}}{\mathrm{d} \theta} \cdot \sin(\sin(\theta)) \\
  &=& \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} \theta} \left( \mathrm{e}^{\cos(\theta)} \sin(\sin(\theta))  \right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$